# Dispatcher servlet mapping

Tags: spring

I am trying to use spring-security

Before all of the configuration

```
http://localhost:9090/app/login2.xhtml
```

request, works as i expected.

I added a controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class LoginController {


 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getLoginPage(@RequestParam(value="error", required=false) boolean error, 
   ModelMap model) {
return "login2.xhtnml";
}

}
```

I have in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
                classpath:META-INF/spring-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

With this configuration when i call

```
http://localhost:9090/app/login2.xhtml
```

Error comes

```
 WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/login2.xhtml] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

BUT when i change configuration mapping to

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

`http://localhost:9090/app/login2.xhtml` works as i expected

but

```
http://localhost:9090/app/auth/login
```

gives no error, no exception, no redirection, i think dispatcher servlet can not know about this request.

```
http://localhost:9090/app/app/auth/login
```

works with

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

My understanding:

dispatcher servlet use `"http://localhost:9090/"` as base for searching login2.xhtml
and use `"http://localhost:9090/app"` for `/auth/login` URL.

I do not know where to set this, and why they are different.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the `SpringSecurityFilterChain` to the web.xml?

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Could you past the registered "Request Bindings" if the container starts (from the logfile)?

Comment: Thanks for response but i do not have the project anymore, so even if i had achived to have the project run as i expected, i can not tell you the answer i do not remember :)